Digital signal processing from FMCW rangefinder
I am developing a FMCW rangefinder and have encountered a number of questions regarding digital signal processing.
So I have a sawtooth modulating signal with a frequency of 1 kHz, which is fed to the microwave module. The microwave module is based on the BGT24LTR11N16E6327XTSA1 microcircuit from Infineon. From the output I I take the signal, amplify it and pass it through a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of ~15 kHz. Then I feed it to the ADC. The sampling frequency is 48 kHz.
The signal if the module is directed into empty space looks like this:

I see beat frequencies at multiples of 1 kHz.
If there is any movement, I see the Doppler frequency. And depending on the distance at which the movement occurred, as well as the speed and direction, I see the frequency that is offset from the central beat frequency. For example, as shown in the figure, around 5 kHz. The higher the speed, the further the offset from the central beat frequency.
To select this frequency I do the following: first I multiply the input signal by e^(-j(w_c t)) for example, if I need to shift the signal from 5 kHz I multiply by cos⁡(2π∙i∙5/48) and by sin⁡(2π∙i∙5/48). Then I pass the signal through a digital low-pass filter of the 10th order separately for sin and cos. Then I shift the signal to the right by a frequency of 0-1 kHz. Since it will be a multiplication of complex numbers, I take only the real part. LP500cos∙cos(2π∙i∙0.5/48)-LP500sin∙sin(2π∙i∙0.5/48). After which I do decimation by 24. And then I get rid of the central beat frequency by passing the signal through a 495-505Hz notch filter.

It seems to work, but now I have a number of questions:

Am I correctly selecting the signal band I need by shifting it first to the left, then the LPF and then to the right?
I read about decimation in this post. If I understood correctly, before decimation I can accumulate 24 signal samples, then add them up and divide by 24 after decimation?
The most difficult and unclear question for me. I set the signal deviation to 3 meters, that is, I see a signal of 0.5-1.5 kHz when something moves in the range of 0-3 meters. 1.5-2.5 kHz when the movement is in the range of 3-6 meters and so on. I process all ranges up to 30 meters this way. But at the same time I noticed that if something with a high reflectivity (for example, a car) moves at a distance of 45 meters, I still see some signal at frequencies of 9.5-10.5 kHz and at 8.5-9.5 kHz, but with a smaller amplitude, and so on? Why can this happen? Am I filtering the signal uncorrect somewhere? I tried to add a 20th order elliptical LPF with a cutoff frequency of 10.5 kHz with unevenness in the bandwidth of 1dB and -120dB in the cutoff frequency right after I receive the signal from the ADC (before multiplying by cos and sin), but this did not help at all ... I also noticed that if at 45 meters the movement is perpendicular to the radiation axis of the microwave module, the parasitic signal will be maximum and will be at frequencies close to the beat frequency. At the same time, if you even slightly shift the movement (or the radiation axis of the detector), the parasitic signal sharply fades out.

